# Which manufacturer produces mice with high durability buttons?

Tags: mice, durability

My problem is that my computer mice always fail the same way - by malfunctioning main buttons!

I do buy expensive optical cordless mice from Logitech since decades now.
But it's always the same:
First the left mouse button "breaks" (1), then I try to shift most actions to the right one (2), then both of them get unusable. Finally I have to buy another expensive branded product.

[explanations:
(1) By "breaking" I mean defective, loose or even chattering contacts which sometimes fire without my intention to hit the button, reforming single clicks into double or multiple clicks, losing contact while I try to draw something across the screen. ... I think you'll get the picture.
(2) Despite tools or settings to switch the functionality between both main buttons there's mostly the possibility to use context menus or even to use both buttons interchangeably, e.g. if you're working on Android emulators.]

A malfunctioning mouse button like explained can be at least bothersome in some games where you die a lot more often due to these issues - but outside games it can be really dangerous, clicking on arbitrary buttons, choosing options you wouldn’t want to touch, double-clicking things you only want to select, dropping files or other objects to wrong places (Recycle Bin?)!

I really do not want to look at my branded computer mouse as some kind of consumable. I also hit the buttons of my keyboard very often (even if this distributes to much more of them), but I can still use my first keyboards, decades later!

What I’ve done (despite repurchasing):
I’ve already researched the matter of chattering mouse buttons but only found instructions to open the case and try to clean the micro-switches. But with my current Logitech laser mouse I cannot do this. Maybe the sliding points hide the screws. I cannot remove them, because this would destroy the material and I do not know where to get replacement sliding points.

So, to summarize my overall question:
Is there a big manufacturer which produces better quality mice with a higher life expectancy of the buttons than Logitech products?
(I’m not interested in small producers with only local availability.)

Comment: Which model of Logitech mouse have you been using?  I have a 10 year old Dell wired mouse that gets used 10 hours a day with no issues.  That being said I have Logitech Wireless mice almost exclusively throughout my office and have never had this issue.

Comment: Maybe your are just hard on your stuff.  You don't state what kind of usage is going on, hardware can be poorly built, defective, or wear out.  But we don't know what you are doing with your hardware, so we could all suggest what works for us but it might not meet your expectations (or abuse).

Comment: Well, you could try some of the high end gaming mice.  I am using a MadCatz R.A.T. 7.   My previous was a R.A.T.7 when it was made under Saitek, it lasted for years and though heavy....and by that I mean gaming level heavy use.

Comment: Im a logitech fan, been using an m705 since they came out. What I can tell you about them, they hate any kind of dust. I actually bought replacement feet pads, and took my mouse apart and cleaned it with canned air. With that said, what model do you have?

Comment: I've got a Compaq mouse that's still going after 20 years.  Might be a bit difficult to find one, though, since the company went out of business in 2002.

Comment: @Mark Not quite OOB, were absorbed by HP

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a basic mouse without twenty-seven buttons and assignable macros, etc etc: I'd recommend my **[HP BR376AA](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00SXBSKLY)**.

- Five buttons: left, right, scroll, and two "thumb" side keys (which are mapped by default to browser forward/back).
- Excellent durability: I've had it for... five years? without it wearing out in the slightest.
- Around £40/$48, which is on the expensive side for a mouse, but the durability probably saves you enough to make up for it.

Comment: *cough* expensive for a basic mouse.  Also, I am skeptical about HP making the actual mouse........HP and quality have not seemed to go hand in hand in........forever?

Answer (score 1):

The best mouse I ever owned, and really the only mouse I've ever seen with a cult following, is the [Logitech MX518](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015R8M7U). People buy these for $150+ because they were so reliable and no longer newly available. Its successor, the [G400](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055QZ216), is basically the same thing after doubling the DPI of its sensor and taking away the faux-impacted-metal design.

Speaking from experience, my MX518 worked consistently for 9 years until it developed the ole' "thinks a single click is two clicks" issue. Not bad for over 8000 hours of use for its life. It was a very sad day when I retired it and replaced with a Steelseries Sensei (only a year in but hey it's a decent mouse so far).